# Pure javascript (es2015) function to extract child from tree json structure

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6, azure-cosmosdb

I have a DocumentDb database where one of the document-types has the following structure:

```js
{
    "structure": {
        "id": "7d2d5d3f-0c82-4910-aa0b-54d8067588a3",
        "unittype": 1,
        "name": "MyCompany",
        "language": "nb-NO",
        "managers": [],
        "logoURL": null,
        "orginfo": {
            "Orgnumber": null,
            "Country": null,
            "Sector": null,
            "Code": null
        },
        "tags": [],
        "respondents": [],
        "childUnits": [
            {
                "id": "3fb44416-8fa8-4b60-8c0c-03b333d176f7",
                "unittype": 3,
                "name": "Marketing",
                "language": "nb-NO",
                "managers": [],
                "logoURL": null,
                "orginfo": {
                    "Orgnumber": null,
                    "Country": null,
                    "Sector": null,
                    "Code": null
                },
                "tags": [],
                "respondents": [],
                "childUnits": [
                    {
                        "id": "49932d6f-518e-4511-9bc9-f6f747a81968",
                        "unittype": 3,
                        "name": "Internet",
                        "language": "nb-NO",
                        "managers": [],
                        "logoURL": null,
                        "orginfo": {
                            "Orgnumber": null,
                            "Country": null,
                            "Sector": null,
                            "Code": null
                        },
                        "tags": [],
                        "respondents": [],
                        "childUnits": [],
                        "Parent": "3fb44416-8fa8-4b60-8c0c-03b333d176f7"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "aa76010d-ae59-49b1-b929-9572eb536cc6",
                        "unittype": 3,
                        "name": "DM",
                        "language": "nb-NO",
                        "managers": [],
                        "logoURL": null,
                        "orginfo": {
                            "Orgnumber": null,
                            "Country": null,
                            "Sector": null,
                            "Code": null
                        },
                        "tags": [],
                        "respondents": [],
                        "childUnits": [],
                        "Parent": "3fb44416-8fa8-4b60-8c0c-03b333d176f7"
                    }
                ],
                "Parent": "7d2d5d3f-0c82-4910-aa0b-54d8067588a3"
            },
            {
                "id": "be1d142a-e09d-4828-aceb-07d65321da5d",
                "unittype": 3,
                "name": "Support",
                "language": "nb-NO",
                "managers": [],
                "logoURL": null,
                "orginfo": {
                    "Orgnumber": null,
                    "Country": null,
                    "Sector": null,
                    "Code": null
                },
                "tags": [],
                "respondents": [],
                "childUnits": [],
                "Parent": "7d2d5d3f-0c82-4910-aa0b-54d8067588a3"
            }
        ],
        "Parent": null
    },
    "id": "07b4c7c5-7324-4eef-9e4e-9deb70615ec4",
    "type": "organization",
    "owner": "auth0|571f2eb34247998a66726b02",
    "public": false,
    "_rid": "GPFbALqREAMNAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/GPFbAA==/colls/GPFbALqREAM=/docs/GPFbALqREAMNAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"00004707-0000-0000-0000-5881cef40000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1484902132
}
```

This is a rebuild of an old system where everything was stored in a relational database and each `Unit` (objects in the `childUnits` property) was originally a line in a table. Testing with one of our largest customers we end up with a structure with over 500 units. And over 3000 respondents. (I haven't added any in this demo, but the `Respondent` object comprises of an email (required) and possibly a cell-number.)

The result was not good. Running locally on my (rather beefy) devpc the retrieval of the structure takes about 2-3 seconds. And DocumentDb does not support the retrieval of document-parts. So every time a user clicks on a unit in a treeview, the entire structure is resent over the wire (this part I probably could cache, but if the user changes something, I would have to store the entire thing, then read it back).

What DocumentDb *does* support however, is Javascript stored procedures, which uses Chakra, which is ES2015-compliant as far as I can see.

So my thought was to create a stored procedure to which I give the `id` to the document (the organzation) and the `id` for the Unit to retrieve. And it searches through the json document and retrieves just the Unit I want and sends it back.

Is this possible using no external libraries, only ES2015 features?

Answer (score 1):

The best approach for performance would be to leverage the intra-document JOIN - https://www.documentdb.com/sql/demo#JOIN.

Assuming that the structure property is actually part of the document, the JOIN query would look something like this:

```
SELECT c.id, childUnit 
FROM c JOIN childUnit IN c.structure.childUnits 
WHERE c.structure.id = "7d2d5d3f-0c82-4910-aa0b-54d8067588a3" 
    AND childUnit.id = "3fb44416-8fa8-4b60-8c0c-03b333d176f7"*
```

If the *structure* property is not actually part of the original document, the JOIN query would look like this:

```
SELECT c.id, childUnit 
FROM c JOIN childUnit IN c.childUnits 
WHERE c.id = "7d2d5d3f-0c82-4910-aa0b-54d8067588a3" 
    AND childUnit.id = "3fb44416-8fa8-4b60-8c0c-03b333d176f7"*
```

This type of query will return only the specified child unit from your document. The **unit id** and the **childUnit id** in the WHERE filter increases the query performance.

Comment: The ``structure`` property is part of the document and has the same structure as the childUnits. What maybe isn't so clear from the code property is that the units are nested in a tree structure. Each unit has it's own childUnits array containing more units and so on. I think for your example to work you would need to flatten the structure first.
To try and be more clear: The ``structure`` property could just as well have been a ``childUnits`` array with a single unit.

Comment: Recursive data structures are tricky to query in a performant way. I've found that using a fully materialized path approach works best. You can read about this approach [here](http://probablyprogramming.com/2008/07/04/storing-hierarchical-data-in-couchdb), and [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures/).

Answer (score 0):

[Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) solves most of these problems.

If need be you can polyfill the function: [MDN official polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill).

```js
var db = {
    "structure": {
        "id": "7d2d5d3f-0c82-4910-aa0b-54d8067588a3",
        "unittype": 1,
        "name": "MyCompany",
        "language": "nb-NO",
        "managers": [],
        "logoURL": null,
        "orginfo": {
            "Orgnumber": null,
            "Country": null,
            "Sector": null,
            "Code": null
        },
        "tags": [],
        "respondents": [],
        "childUnits": [
            {
                "id": "3fb44416-8fa8-4b60-8c0c-03b333d176f7",
                "unittype": 3,
                "name": "Marketing",
                "language": "nb-NO",
                "managers": [],
                "logoURL": null,
                "orginfo": {
                    "Orgnumber": null,
                    "Country": null,
                    "Sector": null,
                    "Code": null
                },
                "tags": [],
                "respondents": [],
                "childUnits": [
                    {
                        "id": "49932d6f-518e-4511-9bc9-f6f747a81968",
                        "unittype": 3,
                        "name": "Internet",
                        "language": "nb-NO",
                        "managers": [],
                        "logoURL": null,
                        "orginfo": {
                            "Orgnumber": null,
                            "Country": null,
                            "Sector": null,
                            "Code": null
                        },
                        "tags": [],
                        "respondents": [],
                        "childUnits": [],
                        "Parent": "3fb44416-8fa8-4b60-8c0c-03b333d176f7"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "aa76010d-ae59-49b1-b929-9572eb536cc6",
                        "unittype": 3,
                        "name": "DM",
                        "language": "nb-NO",
                        "managers": [],
                        "logoURL": null,
                        "orginfo": {
                            "Orgnumber": null,
                            "Country": null,
                            "Sector": null,
                            "Code": null
                        },
                        "tags": [],
                        "respondents": [],
                        "childUnits": [],
                        "Parent": "3fb44416-8fa8-4b60-8c0c-03b333d176f7"
                    }
                ],
                "Parent": "7d2d5d3f-0c82-4910-aa0b-54d8067588a3"
            },
            {
                "id": "be1d142a-e09d-4828-aceb-07d65321da5d",
                "unittype": 3,
                "name": "Support",
                "language": "nb-NO",
                "managers": [],
                "logoURL": null,
                "orginfo": {
                    "Orgnumber": null,
                    "Country": null,
                    "Sector": null,
                    "Code": null
                },
                "tags": [],
                "respondents": [],
                "childUnits": [],
                "Parent": "7d2d5d3f-0c82-4910-aa0b-54d8067588a3"
            }
        ],
        "Parent": null
    },
    "id": "07b4c7c5-7324-4eef-9e4e-9deb70615ec4",
    "type": "organization",
    "owner": "auth0|571f2eb34247998a66726b02",
    "public": false,
    "_rid": "GPFbALqREAMNAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/GPFbAA==/colls/GPFbALqREAM=/docs/GPFbALqREAMNAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"00004707-0000-0000-0000-5881cef40000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1484902132
};
function getDocument(orgID, docID) {
    //Variable to hold traversal progress
    var extract = db
        .structure
        .childUnits
        .find(function findFunc(organization) {
        return organization.id == orgID;
    });
    //Return false if we found no organization
    if (typeof extract == "undefined") {
        return false;
    }
    //Traverse organization children
    extract = extract
        .childUnits
        .find(function findFunc(document) {
        return document.id == docID;
    });
    //Return false if we found no organization
    if (typeof extract == "undefined") {
        return false;
    }
    //if we reach this point we found a result, which we can then return
    return extract;
}
//Running test
console.log(getDocument("3fb44416-8fa8-4b60-8c0c-03b333d176f7", "aa76010d-ae59-49b1-b929-9572eb536cc6"));
console.log(getDocument("3fb44416-8fa8-4b60-8c0c-03b333d176f7", "ERR"));
console.log(getDocument("ERR", "aa76010d-ae59-49b1-b929-9572eb536cc6"));
console.log(getDocument("ERR", "ERR"));
```

Comment: Has anyone confirmed? Does this work in a stored procedure in DocumentDB?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) with an iterative and recursive style.

```js
function getObject(object, id) {
    var r;
    return function iter(o) {
        if (o.id === id) {
            r = o;
            return true;
        }
        if (Array.isArray(o.childUnits)) {
            return o.childUnits.some(iter);
        }
    }(object) && r || undefined;
}

var data = { structure: { id: "7d2d5d3f-0c82-4910-aa0b-54d8067588a3", unittype: 1, name: "MyCompany", language: "nb-NO", managers: [], logoURL: null, orginfo: { Orgnumber: null, Country: null, Sector: null, Code: null }, tags: [], respondents: [], childUnits: [{ id: "3fb44416-8fa8-4b60-8c0c-03b333d176f7", unittype: 3, name: "Marketing", language: "nb-NO", managers: [], logoURL: null, orginfo: { Orgnumber: null, Country: null, Sector: null, Code: null }, tags: [], respondents: [], childUnits: [{ id: "49932d6f-518e-4511-9bc9-f6f747a81968", unittype: 3, name: "Internet", language: "nb-NO", managers: [], logoURL: null, orginfo: { Orgnumber: null, Country: null, Sector: null, Code: null }, tags: [], respondents: [], childUnits: [], Parent: "3fb44416-8fa8-4b60-8c0c-03b333d176f7" }, { id: "aa76010d-ae59-49b1-b929-9572eb536cc6", unittype: 3, name: "DM", language: "nb-NO", managers: [], logoURL: null, orginfo: { Orgnumber: null, Country: null, Sector: null, Code: null }, tags: [], respondents: [], childUnits: [], Parent: "3fb44416-8fa8-4b60-8c0c-03b333d176f7" }], Parent: "7d2d5d3f-0c82-4910-aa0b-54d8067588a3" }, { id: "be1d142a-e09d-4828-aceb-07d65321da5d", unittype: 3, name: "Support", language: "nb-NO", managers: [], logoURL: null, orginfo: { Orgnumber: null, Country: null, Sector: null, Code: null }, tags: [], respondents: [], childUnits: [], Parent: "7d2d5d3f-0c82-4910-aa0b-54d8067588a3" }], Parent: null }, id: "07b4c7c5-7324-4eef-9e4e-9deb70615ec4", type: "organization", owner: "auth0|571f2eb34247998a66726b02", public: false, _rid: "GPFbALqREAMNAAAAAAAAAA==", _self: "dbs/GPFbAA==/colls/GPFbALqREAM=/docs/GPFbALqREAMNAAAAAAAAAA==/", _etag: "\"00004707-0000-0000-0000-5881cef40000\"", _attachments: "attachments/", _ts: 1484902132 };

console.log(getObject(data.structure, 'foo'));
console.log(getObject(data.structure, 'aa76010d-ae59-49b1-b929-9572eb536cc6'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```